# Match and align Excel data from various columns

Tags: excel, sorting

I have seen lots of questions similar to this; but none that would work with my data.

Please, feel free to direct me to the appropriate thread - I have tried and failed to find one!

I have two product lists, this one (which is from the website):

```
 BC SKU   BC Product   BC Price   BC Cost
 0        Product xx   £130.50    £86.93    
 0        Product xx   £0         £0       
 10       Product xx   £5         £15.10    
 149      Product xx   £1.35      £2.10     
 188      Product yy   £21.89     £23.89
```

And this one (which is from the manufacturer):

```
NVS SKU   NVS Product  NVS Cost
61        product xx   £269.86
97        product xx   £282.32
188       product yy   £24.62
```

The list from the website has around 5,000 entries, and the manufacturer has around 15,000.

I would ideally like a list that would combine the products information, but only for products found on both lists (ie, products that are being sold on the website).

The perfect end result would be:

```
BC SKU   BC Product   BC Price   BC Cost   NVS Cost   NVS SKU
188      Product yy   £21.89     £23.89    £24.62     188
```

As you can imagine, the products will have to be matched via the SKU as the Product titles are slightly different. The product SKU's are the only thing that match.

Can anyone help - I'm punching slightly above my weight here?

Comment: @pnuts Wouldn't that just tell me if there was a match? Would this be able to compile the data into one row?

Comment: @SDemeda - No, [it gives you more than that](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Comment: Are there unique data points that are contained in both lists? What I mean by this is are the BC Product and NVS Product the same thing, or are BC SKU and NVS SKU the same?

Comment: @user2696883 As mentioned in the question, the unique data points are the BC SKU & NVS SKU. So there are matching parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple VLOOKUP for this. Let's say you are using the website list as your master list, add two columns after the BC cost column. In the first, use the following formula (assuming that BC SKU is column A):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,FALSE),"")
```

And in the next column:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,1,FALSE),"")
```

If you copy these formulae throughout the worksheet it will copy over the NVS Cost and NVS SKU for each item that can be found in the manufacturer list. I have added an IF statement so that all #N/A values (i.e. any items not found on the other sheet) will show as blanks rather than show as errors. If you replace the '1' in the last formula with a '3', then this will give you NVS Cost rather than NVS SKU, provided the data is in columns A through to C.

Comment: I'll give that a try now.

Comment: You could also handle that potential #N/A error with a (slightly simpler) =iferror function.

Comment: @user2696883 This worked perfectly using your first answer. Thank you very much.